# does only keras or backend function can be used in custom loss function?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

when defining a custom loss function, i want to:

operate the input y_pred tensor with numpy
process the input y_pred tensor to a external binary execution and get a result
demo code like below:

```
def mse_my_loss(y_true,y_pred):

Q1 = K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)    
y_in = y_pred.numpy()    
file_wave = './tools/data.raw'
librosa.output.write_wav(file_wave, y_pred, 16000)
CMD = './tools/EVAL +16000 ' + file_wave
os.system(CMD)    
loss = readresult()    
return Q1 + loss
```

whether it's feasible to achieve this?

Or only keras or backend function can be used in a customed loss function to let keras perform automatic gradient calculation on tensor？

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only backend functions can be used for this, as Keras needs to compute gradients of the loss function with respect of the weights, and only backend functions are symbolic (and thus propagate gradients).